# owncloud - uwsgi, cron and php issue

Tags: php, cron, uwsgi, owncloud

I have a running owncloud installation with Arch Linux, nginx, uwsgi-php. 
Now I'm trying to use the cron like interface of uwsgi to enable the cronjob for cron.php in owncloud.

php.ini remains default. I'm using php-set option in the uwsgi ini file to enable all extensions.

```
# load all extensions only in this instance of php, no need to edit global php.ini
php-set = extension=bz2.so
....
php-set = extension=apcu.so

php-set = apc.ttl=7200
php-set = apc.enable_cli=1

cron2 = minute=-3,unique=1 /usr/bin/php -d open_basedir="/usr/share/webapps/owncloud:/tmp/: \
/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/owncloud/data:/etc/webapps/" \
-d date.timezone=Etc/UTC \
-d extension=pdo_mysql.so -d extension=apcu.so \
-d apc.enable_cli=1 -f /usr/share/webapps/owncloud/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Problem is I would have to use the -d option for all extensions I enabled earlier in the ini file, just because the command line cron job doesn't have these information.

Is there a way to remain in the php instance of uwsgi for the cron command? Or do I have to edit the global php.ini which uwsgi and cron could use?